# Rxjs with redux-observable. Repeat action

Tags: redux, rxjs, rxjs5, redux-observable

I have an epic like this:

```
export const fetchCharacter = (id) =>
  ajax({ url: `https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}` })
    .map(response => fetchCharacterSuccess(response.body))
    .catch(error => Observable.of(fetchCharacterFailure(error.response.body)));

export const startFetchingCharacters = () => ({ type: START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS });

export const fetchUserEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS)
    .delay(3000)
    .mergeMap(
      action => api.fetchCharacter(store.getState().nextCharacterId)
    );
```

Right now it only listens for `START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS` action and makes **one** request for the user.

Now I would like to keep fetching characters over and over(with delay) until some cancellation action. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Map an `.interval()` observable to the api fetch (or a `.timer()` depending on the exact pattern of delay you want).

Stop it with a `takeUntil()`.

```js
const delay = 3000
const fetchUserEpic = (action$, store) =>
  action$.ofType(START_FETCHING_CHARACTERS)
    .mergeMap( action => 
      Observable.interval(delay)
        .mergeMap(x => api.fetchCharacter(store.getState().nextCharacterId) )
        .takeUntil(action$.ofType(STOP_FETCHING_CHARACTERS))
    );
```

---

**Footnote**

Strictly speaking, the inner `mergeMap()` does not guarantee the order of character return. Since `api.fetchCharacter()` is asynchronous, it's possible for fetch's to return out of order (although a long delay of 3s helps avoid that).

Using `concatMap()` on the inner observable makes sure emits happen in strict `nextCharacterId()` order.

```js
Observable.interval(delay)
  .concatMap(x => api.fetchCharacter(store.getState().nextCharacterId) )
```

Comment: I used `mergeMap` instead of `flatMap` not sure is it a difference. I guess not.

Comment: You're right, they are the same. From the source code, `exports.flatMap = mergeMap_2.mergeMap;`